# Formatting wiggle inspite of using String.format in Swing component

Tags: java, swing, string-formatting, number-formatting

I am using

```
String.format("w:%5d h:%5d n:%5d",a,b,c);
```

to show space padded `int`s in a `JLabel` as the mouse moves over a `JFrame`. Thinking it might be a label artifact, I added a `JFormattedTextField` for good measure but it suffers with  the same problem: the text dances around as the coords change from single to multi-digit. How to solve this?

Here's some example code

```java
package all.code.classes;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;


public class rough3 {


    static String toString(int a,int b,int c)
    {
        return String.format("w:%5d h:%5d n:%5d",a,b,c);

    }
    JFormattedTextField ftf=new JFormattedTextField();
    JLabel la=new JLabel();

    static int x,y;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()-> {

            rough3 xx = new rough3();
            xx.la.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            JFrame fr = new JFrame();
            fr.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            fr.getContentPane().add(xx.ftf, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            fr.getContentPane().add(xx.la, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            fr.setSize(500, 100);
            fr.setVisible(true);
            fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            fr.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    super.mouseMoved(e);
                    x = e.getX();
                    y = e.getY();
                    xx.ftf.setText(xx.toString(x,y,1));
                    xx.la.setText(xx.toString(x,y,135));

                }
            });

        });
    }




}
```

Comment: Are you using a fixed-width font? If not, you may need to split the three parts across three labels to get it "pixel-perfect".

Comment: @Thilo thnx..do elaborate..i am using whatever swing is using by default...haven't touched any fonts at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add these lines.

```
xx.ftf.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
xx.la.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

Comment: `new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12)` While `Font.PLAIN` is a constant which provides the advantage of compile-time checking, `"monospaced"` is not. Instead use `Font.MONOSPACED` (check spelling, or let the IDE / compiler do it for you!).

Comment: @saka1029 so the problem was the font. Since there isn't a built-in way in jdk way to find if the default font is monospaced or not, does one have to always use a custom monsopaced font to be sure there is  no wiggle ? (the Font.MONOSPACED doesn't suit the apps laf)